# Android: Dynamically asscociating data type with an activity

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have a use case in my application, where after certain point, I need to associate an data with an activity. So whenever an intent with an action and the data type is fired, my activity can be opened. I know that it is possible to associate a data type with an activity statically via AndroidManifest.xml.

Is it possible to register the data type for an activity dynamically and programatically ?
Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it possible to register the data type for an activity dynamically and programatically ?

No.

If the `<intent-filter>` you want is known in advance, but you only want to enable it after a certain point, you may be able to achieve this via `<activity-alias>` (have it disabled at the outset and enable it programmatically via `PackageManager`). Alas, `<intent-filter>` does not appear to be something you can enable or disable, at least based on what I see in the manifest documentation.

Comment: Yeah! You're correct. I would really like to see this feature in android.

Comment: This helped me to fit one of my use case regarding launcher screen. Thanks !