# Can I define a dynamic intent-filter in my Android application?

Tags: java, android, dynamic, android-intent, intentfilter

I can define `intent-filter`(s) in `AndroidManifest.xml`; works great.  Is there an API to register them dynamically? My application allows users to configure "accounts" to various servers; I'd like to start capturing actions going to those servers, but since they are dynamic I won't know them at compile time.

This is what I was asking: [Android: Dynamically asscociating data type with an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133844/android-dynamically-asscociating-data-type-with-an-activity)

Answer (score 7):

This might be useful to you. I use this so my receiver can get a call when the screen off intent happens. this particular intent doesn't seem to work if you try to declare it in the manifest.

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```