# How to intercept presetted links to open my android app?

Tags: java, android, url, android-intent, url-interception

I am developing an issue tracking application for android platform. So i need to open link to an issue in my application.
I know how to intercept links with setted in AndroidManifest.xml schemas (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609573/intercepting-links-from-the-browser-to-open-my-android-app), but my problem is that I don't know which schema I am gonna work with. 
My current AndroidManifest.xml looks like

```
<activity android:name=".activity.InterceptionActivity" >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:host="*" android:scheme="http"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

So I open every links from browser, and this is not a good way.

There are ulr examples:

1. Issue url from my tracker -
   http://strintec.myjetbrains.com/youtrack/issue/YD-176 android:scheme
   is "http", android:host is "strintec.myjetbrains.com"
2. Issue url from another tracker - http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-16912
   android:scheme is "http", android:host is "youtrack.jetbrains.com"

My point is I don't know what tracker url gonna be looks like.
Only one thing in common - "/issue/" part, and I've tried to use android:pathPattern but it doesn't work (maybe i've done it wrong).

Is there any solution how to set links schemas within an already installed app?
Or something else advice.
Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't look like you can add an intent-filter other than in the manifest. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133844/android-dynamically-asscociating-data-type-with-an-activity .